# Fixing menu on top with jquery. menu doesn't appears later when scrolled down?

Tags: jquery, header, navigation

I want to make navigation bar nav below the header to appear on the top of screen when scrolled down!
Menu doesnt immediately appears when scrolled down. It appears after further scrolling down!

Also can someone please explain me this? $(window).height() - 70; I am nit able to figure out what it will return.

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav").slideDown(800);

    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        var navHeight = $(window).height() - 70;
        if ( $(window).scrollTop()> navHeight){
            $('.nav').addClass('fixed');
            $('.nav').css("display","none");
            $('.nav').fadeIn("fast");
        }
        else{
            $('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
            $('.nav').css("display","block");
        }
    });

});
```

my html code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-container">
        Logo goes here!!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="main-body">
    <div class="article-area">
        <div class="article">
            <h3>This is the title</h3>
            <hr>
            <img src="imgtest.jpg"></img>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="article">
            <h3>This is the title</h3>
            <hr>
            <img src="imgtest.jpg"></img>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-area">
        ertertre
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

My css code:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #cccccc;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#header{
    background: #FF9900;
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header-container{
    width: 960px;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display:none; /*hiding it for cool jquery slide down effect*/
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    height: 70px; 
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav .nav-container{
    width: 960px;
    height: 62px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav .nav-container ul{
    padding-top: 6px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav .nav-container ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    background: #000000;
}

.nav .nav-container ul li a{
    color: #FF9900;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 58px;
    line-height: 250%;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.nav .nav-container ul li a:hover{
    background:#FF9900;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px; 
}

.main-body{
    width: 960px;
    background: white;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height: 700px;
}

.article-area{
    width: 600px;
    min-height: 700px;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.sidebar-area{
    width: 280px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background: green;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
}

.article{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #FAFAF8;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 4px black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.article p{
    width: 550px;
}

.article img{
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.article h3{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin:0px;
}

.upper-footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hysteris version of menu fixing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".nav").slideDown(800);

// glueMenu use for hysteresis, jittery in transition.
// also, want outside callback for persistance.
var gluedMenu = false;

$(window).on('scroll',function(){

    // glue on when scroll past header container plus your fixed position in CSS
    var navHeight1 = $('.header-container').height() + 70;

    // unglue when scroll past returns back 10 pixels after fixed position
    var navHeight2 = $('.header-container').height() + 60;

    if ( $(window).scrollTop()> navHeight1 ) {
      if (gluedMenu == false) {
        gluedMenu = true;
        $('.nav').addClass('fixed');
        $('.nav').css("display","none");
        $('.nav').fadeIn("fast");
      }
    }
    else if ( $(window).scrollTop() < navHeight2 ) {
      if (gluedMenu == true) {
        gluedMenu = false;
        $('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.nav').css("display","block");
      }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: thanks for your reply! but i want to fix the menu as soon as nav is finished. I want the effect to be smooth! While scrolling down menu becomes fixed before scroll is completed. It gets fixed in header too! I want to avoid it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no reason to add `display: none`. using fadeIn is enough. Second of all, with every scroll you are executing the function! this is a no no. instead, we can add some extra logic to make sure we aren't endlessly executing the callback, but only if the state changes of the nav element. Also instead of using `display: none` / `display: block`, we can just `fadeOut(0).fadeIn('fast')` since animation queue is synchronous in jquery. Lastly, you are erroneously getting `window.height()` and subtracting an arbitrary value of 70 from it. instead, you should should test scrolltop vs the height of the header container, which is 160px. in the second conditional if, we need to add 1 to the header container's height to ensure that the fixed class is removed when scrolling back up.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav").slideDown(800);

    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        //var navHeight = $(window).height() - 70;
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > $('.header-container').height() && $('.nav:not(.fixed)').length ){
            $('.nav').addClass('fixed').fadeOut(0).fadeIn('fast');
        }
        else if( $(window).scrollTop() < $('.header-container') + 1 && $('.nav.fixed').length ){
            $('.nav').removeClass('fixed').fadeOut(0).fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nk48nc9r/7/)

Comment: It is working perfectly in jsfiddle but my browser i.e chrome is causing me errors. I only copied

Comment: Also can you explain a little what you have written in if bracket. Forgive me I am a noob

Comment: what errors are you seeing? i'm fairly certain the error probably relates to some other code in your page

Comment: @killerprince182 if window scroll height greater than header height and nav not fixed exists do blah blah blah. else if scroll height less than header height and nav fixed exists do blah blah blah. this insures that your event will only fire one time in either direction.

Comment: thanks for your help but the code is not working while scrolling up! I have tried it in operA and chrome!
its working while scrolling down!

Comment: In chrome, opera and other webkit browsers, the scroll event doesn't fire until you stop scrolling.as soon as you stop scrolling the event will fire.

Comment: no you didint understand the problem, the problem is the navigation is not returning to original position after scrolling up. You should try running code in browsers.You will get what i am trying to say!